# What's the best way to store images in android?

Tags: android

What is the best way to store images in android?
Also is it possible to access jsp pages from a web service call in android and how to do it?

Thanks,
Sneha

Comment: @ Sneha You want to store images in External Storage like SD Card?

Comment: you have two completely unrelated questions in the same thread. Maybe you should separate them ?

Answer (score 7):

There are many similar question in SO. You should first search.

> What is the best way to store images
>   in android?

1. [Efficient Way to store images in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393494/efficient-way-to-store-images-in-android)
2. [what is the best practice store images in android in SD card or in SQL lite DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539130/what-is-the-best-practice-store-images-in-android-in-sd-card-or-in-sql-lite-db)

> is it possible to access jsp pages
>   from a web service call in android and
>   how to do it?

Can't get what you want exactly but if you wanna call web service in android then...

1. [How to call a SOAP web service on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-web-service-with-android)
2. [calling a webservice in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562012/calling-a-webservice-in-android)
3. [Threaded web service call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797478/threaded-web-service-call)