# Android : Image and Audio Optimization/Compression/Minification

Tags: android, compression, image-compression

I am developing an android application that consists of a collection of images as well as audio files.

What is the appropriate file format I should you (for the image and the audio files) which will not make the size of the application huge?

Comment: bit map or nine patch image or you can try with convert image to byte array android

Comment: @Sreekanth Thanks for the answer. Could you please elaborate or link source code on how to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5729305 and http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/store-imagesfiles-database